# How to set up Category Rules (using Visual Merchandiser?)

Tags: magento2, product, category

I would like to create a Category that would automatically contain Products of a certain Brand (an attribute). When looking for a solution, I found a lot of info about creating Category Rules.

There is supposed to be a switch called "Match products by rule" in the "Products in category" section, but in my set up (CE 2.2.2) it is simply not there.

As shown here: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/category-product-rules.html

Can you please tell me how to display the switch so I can start using Category rules? Is Visual Merchandiser necessary for this? If so, how do I install it?

Alternatively, can you please suggest another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Found another solution that does virtually the same by installing this extension. Hope it helps someone in the future:

https://github.com/karliuka/m2.SmartCategory

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, this is a commerce-only feature in Magento 2 so you will not see it. Yes, there are other extensions that will provide the functionality in CE.